# How to pass the result data from previous step (groovy code) to the editable email notification step?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins job which is running to test my code in managed environments, after it run successfully, I need call a API to get the environment info and consolidate all the test result and environment info together as the email body and send via email.

I am able to call the API successfully in groovy and get the environment info back.
I am using the editable email notification in my jenkins to send out email. 
I want to use injected environment variable(for example MESSAGE_BODY) where groovy can set the email body and then Editable Email Notification could refer that environment variable easily as messagecontent:

Hi all,

This is test result:
  $MESSAGE_BODY

Thanks,

my name

Attached my groovy code below, but it seems that it is not able to set he value for the environment variable.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonException
import hudson.model.*

def environmentInfo= "http://myenvionment/getInfo".toURL().
    getText(requestProperties: [Authorization:'Basic******'],Accept: 'application/json'])

$MESSAGE_BODY = environmentInfo;
```

I want the Editable Email Notification plugin in jenkins could get the groovy result  by referring $MESSAGE_BODY but seems it always null.

I have another idea that I could have groovy write the result to a file, and Editable Email Notification plugin read it, but I not know how to read it from Email Notification plugin and set it to email body content.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the environment variable with the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)